# Why such a big speed difference between 2D gaussian filtering with skimage and scipy compared to MATLAB's imgaussfilt?

Tags: python, performance, matlab, image-processing, filtering

I am seeking to migrate workflow from MATLAB to Python. I will be doing a lot of filtering of large images and immediately hit a performance roadblock. Filtering a 11587 by 13744 in MATLAB R2022a with a 10 sigma Gaussian filter takes under two seconds:

```
tic, imgf=imgaussfilt(im,10); toc
Elapsed time is 1.792801 seconds.
```

I try the same thing with `scipy` 1.8.0 and `skimage` 0.19.1 and both are far slower:

```
%timeit scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(im, 10, truncate=2)
4.89 s ± 15.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Slower by 2.7 times.

```
%timeit skimage.filters.gaussian(im, sigma=10, preserve_range=True, truncate=2)
5.99 s ± 14.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Slower by 3.4 times.

Note that `truncate` is set to 2, which I understand matches what MATLAB is doing. I have verified that the output images look the same, so nothing basic is wrong.

Is there a solution for specifically speeding up this operation (and similar image processing tasks) in Python? Are some libraries generally considered faster than others? Already, above, I see that `scipy` is quicker, for instance.

**EDIT**:

- opencv is faster than the above two but still slower than MATLAB by a factor of 1.4 or so. This is getting into useful territory, however. opencv is multi-threaded, which seems to explain the difference.
- dip (see below) is faster than MATLAB.  `dip.Gauss(img,10,truncation=2)` executes in just over a second.
- Even better, I have found that my images do not have to be 16 bit and opencv is capable of filtering my 8 bit images in 600 ms! MATLAB, weirdly, takes 13 seconds to filter such an image. So I think we have a winner here.

Comment: MATLAB is basically a corporation whos goal for years is wirtting code that is so efficient that you will pay their expensive software licenses. It makes sense they are fast. Among other things, I believe standard `numpy` and `scipy` are not multithreaded, while MATLAB will always use all your cores.

Comment: that's a mere factor of difference. **what CPU** do you have anyway? do you know?

Comment: I often found opencv faster than scipy when it comes to images, you could try: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html

Comment: That's a good point, Ander. I might be that if I start batching the analysis and running in parallel then  the difference will narrow.

Comment: Yes, @dankal444, I just tested opencv, It is faster than the above two. It's 1.4 times slower than MATLAB, but the difference is starting to get workable at this point.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) to gain more performance you may want to switch to lower precision, float32 (assuming you are working with float64?)

Comment: I am uint16 already, unfortunately, @dankal444.

Comment: So I looked at what is happening with the cores using `htop`. Indeed MATLAB is mult-threading it and scipy is single threaded. opencv is multi-threaded. I'll look into ways of getting it running faster. Maybe there is something basic I'm missing there.

Comment: You could try `dip.Gauss` in [DIPlib](https://diplib.org) (disclosure: I'm an author). It knows an IIR implementation of the Gaussian filter that is much faster for large sigma than the standard FIR implementation. It's also multithreaded.

Comment: Also, 2*sigma is kinda small for a Gaussian filter, use it only if speed is more important than a correct result.

Comment: On my machine, for an image of the size you mention here, but using truncation=3, I see 6.2s for scipy.ndimage, 5.6s for skimage, and 0.75s for DIPlib (but as I said, it's not a fair comparison because it uses a different algorithm).

Comment: I tried `dip.Gauss(img,10,truncation=2)`, @CrisLuengo, and I get 1 second execution time, which is a good deal faster than MATLAB. Which is the best page for me to look at regarding feature discovery?

Comment: @dankal444 -- opencv and 8 bit images is really fast! 600 ms. I lose no information to the eye by going to 8 bit.

Comment: Some DIPlib basics in Python can be discovered here: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/tree/master/examples/python -- Look at the online documentation for a full list of functions sorted by category: https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/modules.html (note "modules" there are not Python modules, just a grouping in the documentation).

Comment: Do compare `dip.Gauss(..., method="fir")` to `dip.Gauss(..., method="iir")`, the IIR filter is typically faster for larger sigma; by default it uses the IIR filter for sigma>10, which is just above your value, but the best cut over depends on your machine, so try both. With 8-bit images you have less data to pipe to the CPU, so it'll be faster. The DIPlib FIR filter is a little bit faster than OpenCV's, but from Python you cannot control the output data type, so it'll output a float, which would cost more time.

Comment: In this case fir is faster by a factor of two.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB's `imgaussfilt` chose, by the dimensions of data, whether to use spatial domain processing or Fourier domain processing.

In some cases its choice, might create optimized calculation which explains the gains you see.

If you're after the fastest spatial filtering using Gaussian Filter you probably should use Intel IPP.

Answer (score 0):

In summary: The best solution I have found for my use case is to convert from 16 bit to 8 bit and use opencv. DIPlib would be faster if I didn't wish to move to 16 bit. The major reason for slower performance with some Python packages seems to be due to them not being multi-threaded, compared to MATLAB's functions which are.